# jQuery user input to control option of one jquery function

Tags: jquery, ajax, input

I'd like an input to control that :

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "get",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   url: "http://www.foo.com/something.php",
   data: {numberInput: "NUMBER I WANT TO CONTROL" },
```

On the HTML side I've

```
 <input type="text" id="jqueryControl" />
```

I want when a user enters a number into the `jqueryControl` to insert it in the .ajax function and reload the data according to the new value entered.

Any idea to do that please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's more like `.ajax()` to get the value. Given that code, it should be:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "get",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   url: "http://www.foo.com/something.php",
   data: { numberInput: $('#jqueryControl').val() },
   ...});
```

Of course, you should trigger the ajax on somehow, for example on change using the event handler:

```
$('#jqueryControl').change(function(){ $.ajax({ ... }); });
```